# Running ionic apps in an Android Emulator.

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new in ionic framework,and want to run the app I made into an Android emulator. I type this command,

```
ionic emulate android
```

and get this error.

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

I have all the path variables set up correctly I think.

**PATH**

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local;C:\Users\W\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin;C:\Users\Theodosios\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin
```

**JAVA_OPTIONS**

```
-Xmx512M
```

Any ideas what is wrong and how can it be fixed?

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this commands on console

1. `npm install -g npm`
2. `npm install -g ionic cordova`
3. `npm install -g angular-cli`

and setting the "Environment Variables"

1. `JAVA_HOME`
2. `ANDROID_HOME`
3. `AVD`

Answer (score 0):

**1) Options**
Remove android platfrom and install again.

**Remove platform**

> $ cordova platform remove android

**Add Platform**

> $ cordova platform add android

**2) Options**

Open SDK manager => Run as administrator 
You will require: 
1) SDK Platform 
2) Android SDK Platform-tools 
3) Andoid SDK tools

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but it didn't help. :(.